# Maximal number of root-directed paths

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, dynamic-programming

I got this question I have to solve with recursive method, and based on the recursive method to build a dynamic programming solution.
I would be grateful for help, mainly with the recursive solution.

Given a rooted-tree T and a number K. root-directed path is defined to be a path in which every vertex is a parent of the vertex before him in the path.
Goal: find the maximum number of dinstinct (no common vertices) of root-directed paths of length k in T

for example: for the tree in the picture and k=3 the answer is: 3
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fct6T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `DP_in(u,k)` as the maximum number of distinct (no common vertices) of root-directed paths of length `k` in the tree subrooted on `u` with `u` in the path.

Also, define `DP_out(u,k)` as the maximum number of distinct (no common vertices) of root-directed paths of length `k` in the tree sub rooted on `u` with `u` NOT in any path.

I will first handle  `DP_out(u,k)`. If `u` is not in any path, then you need the maximum root-directed-paths of length `k` which are sub rooted at any of the children of `u`. So we have:

`DP_out(u,k)=Sum i=1 to r [max(DP_in(v_i, k-1), DP_out(v_i, k)) ]` where `v_1, ..., v_r` are the children of `u`.

Now as for `DP_in(u,k)`, since `u` is in the path, then one, and only one,  of the children of `u` must be in the path that contains `u`. Hence we have that:

`DP_in(u,k)= max (DP_in(v_i, k-1)+ Sum j=1 to r, j=/=i [max(DP_in(v_j, k-1), DP_out(v_j, k))] )` over `i=1,...,r.`

If `r` is the root node of your tree, then the answer that you want is in fact `max( DP_in(r,k), DP_out(r,k))`.

You can build the DP table simultaneously from the bottom of the tree (leaves) and going up to ensure the order of filling the tables is okay.

We know that there are `O(n^2)` sub problems, and each subproblem of  `DP_out(u,k)` can be computed in `O(n)` while each subproblem of `DP_in(u,k)` can be computed in `O(n^2)` naively. So a total of worst case `O(n^4)`.

Note that I am of course not claiming that my method is the most optimum one, there is most probably a slightly optimized way (using some DS), however, I would leave that for you to pursue if you're interested in it.

Comment: so what exactly is your stop condition? a leaf? a node which it's height is less than k?

Comment: @OriNetanelBen-Zaken Any node whose height is less than $k$, return 0 in that cases cause none of the path are of length k.

Comment: Also, if you feel the answer addresses your question appropriately, feel free to accept it by clicking the check matrk under the upvote/downvote :)